# Which UI/UX sketching software is recommended?

Tags: sketching

Which UI/UX sketching software do you use and would recommend? Why?

Comment: Since these have already been metioned below, I will just say I like [Axure](http://www.axure.com/) at work, for home use I'm starting with [Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Home.aspx)

Comment: I'd prefer this question be converted to Community Wiki rather than outright closed.

Comment: Although it doesn't strictly conform to the desired question structure I found the answers to be really informative!

Answer (score 97):

**Software Options**
For software, ***[Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/)*** is great for simplicity, ***[Omnigraffle Pro](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/)*** is great for complexity (with templates from Konigi and others off of [Graffletopia.com](http://graffletopia.com/).

**Sketching Is Way Better To Start With**
Nothing beats sketching for getting your ideas out quickly, iterating easily, and not feeling too "in love" with creations that need to die.

**Tools for Sketching**
These are the tools I use, Ultra Fine Sharpies in black, red, and blue, a Fine Point Sharpie in black, and a Prismacolor Warm Grey 40% marker with broad and fine tips. That warm grey marker will take your sketching to another level in terms of communicating clearly what you mean.

[image: Sketching Tools]

**Tips for Sketching**
Sketching doesn't have to be fancy. Straight lines, text, a little shading … that's all you need to communicate volumes that can't be written. That said, I'll let my sketches tell the rest of the story.

[image: Boxes and Shading]
[image: Types of Text]
[image: Sketch Resolution]

**Sources**
Leah Buley has terrific resources on sketching and has influenced what I know. She works at Adaptive Path as a UX Designer.

Here is [Adaptive Path's Favorite Tools for Sketching](http://adaptivepath.com/ideas/our-favorite-tools-for-sketching).

And check out Slides 16 & 25 of [Leah Buley's Good Design Faster presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/pboersma/good-design-faster-at-ux-sofia).

-----UPDATE------

In order to be able to collaborate better with co-workers, and give everyone a fair shot at drawing out their ideas who might not otherwise feel artistically inclined, we use myBalsamiq and love it.

Comment: Those are really pretty sketches. There's no way I could accomplish something so legible without software unless I spent a LOT of time. Software is way quicker for me. I will at times resort to a whiteboard in order to communicate something to another person in less than 10 seconds.

Comment: Off topic, but wanted to +1 for making cancel both red, AND a link (rather than a button). I don't see that model often enough.

Comment: Admittedly, not entirely on topic. But I do answer the question, LOL.

Comment: oh sorry, didn't mean to imply your answer was off topic...my comment was. ;)

Comment: Glad you like the red cancel link. My designers push back on it, for some reason. They seem to prefer red, no underline or blue underline. Go figure.

Comment: @tajmo What's greeking?

Comment: @Svish Greeking is placeholder text or to gray bars (or lines) representing text. I generally say "lorem ipsum" when using lorem ipsum text, and greeking when using lines or gray bars.  http://desktoppub.about.com/cs/basic/g/greeking.htm

Comment: @tajmo Ah, cool. Didn't know that!

Comment: Fantastic answer.  I like "greeking" too, that's a great word for it, even though "lorem ipsum" is in Latin!

Comment: +1 for "Balsamiq is great for simplicity, Omnigraffle Pro is great for complexity". "Use the right tool for the job" as they say.

Answer (score 16):

**Pencil and paper is the best and most cost effective tool you will ever find.**

Quick, simple, and you can explore many ideas (as you should) with minimal effort.

Comment: I agree, but am asking for software recommendations. It seems easier to share with other people. Do you scan your every drawing or do you replace pen and paper with a tablet?

Comment: @ipavlic When you say "share" what do you mean? Collaborate on from different locations, or just share locally?

Comment: Different locations -- I prefer drawing on paper/whiteboard locally.

Comment: So do you collaborate on the design, or is your use case more being able to show the sketches to stakeholders?

Comment: I agree. Sketching is best as a sketch. Paper, pencil, white boards, markers, etc. To share, I pull out the cell phone, snap a picture, and email.

Comment: While pencil and paper are certainly useful, they are not necessarily the "minimal effort" solution. It's a lot easier to move things around and try different colors/styles with software than with pencil and paper.

Comment: Colors and styles should be coming at later stages of the design, far later than the initial sketches at least.

Comment: Well, UI and UX sketching are different levels of fidelity, IMHO. UX should be low-fi as much as you can.

Comment: It's fast, but messy to share. You have different versions all over the place.

Comment: @b01 you ALWAYS have different versions all over the place. This is why so many are pushing for Lean UX and Agile methods in UX.

Comment: He's asking about software. This is a silly answer.

Comment: Sometimes the best answer isn't necessarily confined to the original question. (Actually, that in itself is a big part of designing UX)

Comment: @jessegavin Not a silly answer. Not sketching enough initially and going digital too quickly is a common pitfall many people run into. To answer the question more directly: What software would I recommend? *No* software.

Answer (score 10):

For exploring loose ideas (alone or in person), I use paper or whiteboard. When I'm preparing low fidelity wireframes for presentation, I use [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups).

Things I like about Balsamiq:

- Lots of existing drop in UI components (including community created)
- I can easily save custom symbols for reuse
- Keyboard shortcuts make adding components fast (for me)
- Some (limited) click-through support for connecting wireframes in a
  pseudo-prototype form
- Saves sketches in a custom XML syntax (BMML) that I can parse with my
  own tools

They've deployed an online, collaboration focused version called [myBalsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups/mybalsamiq), but I have not tried it yet so I cannot offer an opinion.

Comment: myBalsamiq is pretty good. I found drafting up stuff to be surprisingly quick and pleasant, if you need to share or collaborate it's great.

Comment: +1 for Balsamiq.  Really enjoy it and is nice when you link your wireframes together that they can all be exported into a clickable pdf.  Great for showing a client or to test on mobile devices.

Answer (score 6):

Leading industry ui/ux prototyping or sketching software's are many in the market. Both online/desktop. It mainly depends on to what level of fidelity/interactions you want to capture on the interface.

Just for Basic - Medium fidelity i suggest you can use Axure with all different libraries/widgets loaded, otherwise your prototyping life is miserable in that.

Axure Widgets

http://www.axure.com/widgetlibraries

http://www.acleandesign.com/2010/04/axure-better-defaults-library-v2/

http://axureland.com/axure_widget_libraries

For Medium - Advanced you can use iRise which has all the features including even dynamic data showing from database on the inteface. BTW, license is seriously very costly where only enterprises can afford

Other than above, here are listing of popluar tools

- [ConceptDraw Pro](http://www.conceptdraw.com/products/conceptdraw-pro-2) Type: Windows App
- [Pidoco](https://pidoco.com/en) Type: Online
- [Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/)
- [Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups) Type: AIR App
- [Mockingbird](https://gomockingbird.com/) Type: Online
- [Pencil](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pencil/) Type: Firefox  Addon
- [iPlotz](http://iplotz.com/) Type:Online / Flash-Flex
- [ProtoShare](http://www.protoshare.com/) Type: Online
- [HotGloo](http://www.hotgloo.com/) Type: Online
- [Lumzy.com](http://lumzy.com/)  Type: online
- [MockFlow](http://mockflow.com/) Type: Online
- [Gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com/) Type: Online
- [Cacoo](https://cacoo.com/) Type: Online
- [Creately](http://creately.com/)  Type: Online / Flash-Flex
- [Lovely Charts](http://www.lovelycharts.com/) Type: Online
- [Mockup Builder](http://mockupbuilder.com/) Type: Online / Silverlight
- [Lucid Chart](http://www.lucidchart.com/)  Type:Online

Comment: I would say that most of these aren't for sketching but prototyping. Especially Axure which locks you in with their pre-defined widgets. I use and really like some of Axure but I never use it in the sketching stage.

Comment: there is also http://flairbuilder.com

Answer (score 4):

The most important part is to **understand when you need to sketch in different mediums and styles**. Learning when to create the ugly dirty sketches that are simple explorations versus creating actual interactive wireframes.

There are many people who draw using illustrator and a tablet, and they are super quick. The nice thing about that medium for instance is that it can be easily modified and sent to others for manipulation.

So you see, the *medium and software* depends on **where you are in your process** but also 
the **habits of whoever creates those sketches**.

### I Use

I use in order of process and fidelity, starting at rough explorations:

1. Paper + Black pen
2. Paper + Thicker Sharpie, Black pen ,Grey marker for nicer highlights
3. Illustrator for one of wires that might need to be modified
4. Axure (but this is not sketching in my mind, it's wireframing and is used because we need interactivity somehow)

Comment: +1 for choosing a tool based on the context, first and foremost.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to pencil and paper sketching, I recommend using a Wacom tablet + [MyPaint](http://mypaint.intilinux.com/). MyPaint is a drawing opensource software with the following features that make it a good choice for sketching:

- **Infinite canvas.** You can always draw at any side of your current sketch since there are no margins.
- **Lots of brushes** You can use lots of different brushes and create your custom collection.
- **Layer support**. You can use different layers for the drawing, the shading or the annotations and change the active layer with a simple keyboard shortcut.
- **Clean UI.** Provides full-screen mode with keyboard shortcuts for showing/hiding UI elements.
- **Save drafts.** Easily save intermediate states and navigate back and forward to experiment variations of your sketches.

MyPaint provides the above features (which are not available on paper) without introducing much of the complexity of most drawing packages (e.g., Fireworks) or prototyping tools (e.g., Axure) which are better suited for other deliverables (such as wireframes or prototypes).

I have created a replica of the hand-drawn sketch by @tajmo to illustrate the use:

[image]

Comment: I'd call this 'digital' paper sketching. The key is that it is still very much simple hand sketching. MyPaint seems to be a great app that I've been meaning to take for a spin.

Comment: I agree that 'hand' sketching is the most practical option. But since the question was asking for software I tried to provide the closest software option to the hand-sketching experience.

Comment: To clarify, I'd certainly call this hand sketching. (I agree with you)

Answer (score 3):

Pen and paper cannot be [mentioned](http://www.inspireux.com/2010/06/28/50-sketching-resources-for-user-experience-designers/) often enough. The flexibility in the early fases is a must-have.

After that:  Axure is what I use, but I've also heard good things about Balsamic.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing will better replace **pencil** and **paper**. And for this, I would recommend the [**Action Method paper**](http://www.actionmethod.com/product/paper) tools from the **Behance Network**. I use their **dot grid** cahier and notebook everyday and it's really professional and beautiful.

What's cool is that they have adapted this Paper Action method to **web, ipad and mobile**. You should check it out.

As of prototyping/wireframing tools (and not sketching), I personaly use **Balsamiq**. Fast, instinctive and efficient. They also have a myBalsamiq website in beta to handle personal project. But this is not free.

In my company, we handle knowledge management via a **Confluence wiki**. We added the balsamiq plugin and this is a very powerful way to handle wireframe within a context.

Finally, for an intermediate way, you can buy a **Wacom Bamboo tablet** and use UI block and template in Photoshop for the best of all worlds.

Hope all those advises will be helpful.

Comment: I would recommend saving the money and simply creating and printing your own dot grid paper and then adapting it to any device or situation.

Answer (score 2):

I'll recommend Adobe Fireworks. It's great because:

1. It's designed for web design so it is really fast
2. You could use symbols for resuable elements such as buttons, windows etc
3. It supports 9-slice scaling
4. You could build fully interactive prototypes without coding
5. [With this wireframe kit](http://www.dragnet.se/webbdesign/websitewireframes.html) you could quickly build pages to test without distracting design
6. And when you are ready you could quickly start to design on top of the sketches and export everything as css and images.

   I've used Fireworks for 7 years and it has saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

Yup. Paper and pencil and pen wins hands-down. All your hand sketching experience will inform any screen "drawing" you do and make it better. I also second the hands-on simplicity of sending scans and photos of your sketches. Design is thinking and form-making. Screen tools that make it too easy to make images do not contribute to thoughtful design.
If you just want images per hour efficiency, then any of the drawing tools mentioned will do.

For wireframes, I looked hard at Balsamiq, Mockflow, Mockingbird, Hotgoo, Protoshare and othes. I choose Mockflow and am happy with it for price, power, UI and results.

Answer (score 1):

my opinion ... Balsamiq is to limiting. As the only UX person in a fortune 100 company tasked with many web applications/portals ... i simply don't have time/luxury of sketching wireframes in Balsamiq with their limited palette. Having gone down that road, I've found that Development teams need more definition to wireframes, hence why i've moved into Illustrator which allows complete control and provides a hybrid to photoshop design files. Prior to Illustrator, Thin sharpy pens and grid paper is essential to work out business requirements and build the gap between requirements and agile development teams. Looking into interactive mockup tools, ie ... fireworks, iRIse, and Axure, but don't want to be limited to their predefined widgets and don't have the time to code.