# How to re-design an app's user interface?

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, android, ios, redesign

I am new to the interaction design field, basically a student.

I have an assignment where I need to research into topic about Interaction Design of applications for smartphones / tablets when you already have an app on old windows desktop or windows mobile..

Is there some literature or some help which I can get.

Comment: I am not exactly sure I follow,Are you looking to redesign an existing Windows phone App or are you trying to under interaction/usability issues or are you trying to port it another medium,say an Android or an iphone

Comment: Just redesign an existing app... Like if say there is an app existing for Windows mobile.. Now if we want an app for Android with similar functionality...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is to re-design a user interface (UI) taking into account [user-centered design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-centered_design) techniques.

To do so, basically **you need to get feedback from the users and then apply common [interaction design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_design_pattern).**

Getting feedback from the user:

- Read the app reviews. Users like to rant, so it's a good source to directly tap into the discontent of the userbase.
- Run [tests to measure and manage de user experience](http://www.measuringusability.com/blog/measure-manage-ux.php) (UX) and [usability](http://www.usabilityfirst.com/usability-methods/usability-testing/).

Using the feedback to build a user-centered app:

- Know what [design patterns are](http://www.deyalexander.com.au/resources/uxd/design-patterns.html).
- Use [wireframing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Website_wireframe) and [sketching](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/14791/ui-ux-sketching-software-recommendation) to desing a new UI, using [design patterns](http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/about/libraries.html).
- Take specially into account [mobile-specific UX guidelines](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/mobile-ux-guidelines.html).
- Once you have approved a design, use the available guidelines for the required OS ([Android Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html), [iOS Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html), [Windows Phone Guidelines [PDF]](http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/8/6/D869941E-455D-4882-A6B8-0DBCAA6AF2D4/UI%20Design%20and%20Interaction%20Guide%20for%20Windows%20Phone%207%20Series.pdf)).

Since you are designing a whole new UI, the development method would normally be in [spiral phases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_model): get feedback from the old UI, develop improvements, get feedback from the improvements, build more improvements, ... and so on.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep your points in mind.. Since mine is a 4 months assignment, so I'll have to model a process for this. I hope I'll be able to come up with a useful process. But I dun know how to share it with others, so that they could also get benefit from it.

Comment: You can report the process in a blog, publish your findings, and participate in this community by asking questions everyone can benefit from or helping other newbies. Best of luck in your assignment :)

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to redesign it for another platform,a good place to start would be to look at the UI design guidelines for for that specific platform.For example,for apple the H[uman interface guidelines (HIG)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/MobileHIG.pdf) document is a good place to start.

Similarly for Windows, There is a Windows Phone 7 Series UI Design & Interaction Guide by MS. [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202915%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

similarly ,[Android UI guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html)

Comment: Basically, i'm trying to figure out a process which can be useful most of the times when you're trying to redesign existing apps to Android / IOS..

Comment: Then you need to look at Mobile best practices in general and combine them with the UI design guidelines while porting apps to Android or IOS phones

Comment: +1 This is probably where anyone looking to port apps across platforms should start.  The only addition I'd make is that if you can get any feedback from users of the current app to get their opinions on the application, it too would be useful.

Comment: A good place to look for feedback would be to look at the reviews left behind by the users at the app stores,sometimes the reviews are too short to tell you anything but if you dig in,you can get some useful material

Comment: Thanks, I will keep your points in mind.. Since mine is a 4 months assignment, so I'll have to model a process for this. I hope I'll be able to come up with a useful process. But I dun know how to share it with others, so that they could also get benefit from it.