# Is it better to ask for 'full name' or 'first name' and 'last name' in a registration form?

Tags: registration, names, profile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [I want to make name input one field instead of first name/Last name. Wise? Worth it?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/15770/i-want-to-make-name-input-one-field-instead-of-first-name-last-name-wise-worth)

I want to know that whether full name or first name and last name is better to ask in user profile or registration form?

For example: My full name is Waheed-ud-din, where it is one name, so no separate firstname or lastname. I can use my family name with it, as lastname. But I usually don't use that. I normally use Hafiz as my firstname that is my nick and most people know me with that.

So should we use display name during registration and during profile completion use fullname? It seems good but problem arise when display name and full name are totally different and we need to show fullname at some places and username/displayname at some other places. Some time user can be confused because of it. What do you think could be the solution?

Comment: see also http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/15770/i-want-to-make-name-input-one-field-instead-of-first-name-last-name-wise-worth/15778#15778

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, the user definitely could be confused if you're not referring to them in a consistent manner and where you display each definitely needs consideration.

I'd suggest looking at websites that use screen names and full names and how they handle each. Twitter, for example, asks for both on sign up.

Depending what your site is about, it may be ok to just skip a full name all together? If you can't skip it and assuming you need more than a name, consider asking the user for additional information on their first login and explain why you need the info.

Also, if your able to use social network logins, you could pull their full name information without their typing it in.

Bottom line, I suggest you make the sign up process as simple as possible (increasing sign ups) and if you need more info, ask for it later (when they already have a stake in your site) and maybe explain why you need it.

Comment: If I will be using fullname then what will I say with welcome message as fullnames are longer and occupy more space while if I will implement social login then how can I get display name?

Answer (score 11):

Simply put - folks from non-English-speaking countries *may not* know what in their full name is the first name and the last name, trust me. This is probably due to the complexity of their names.

So your best bet is to ask for their "Full Name" which would be a lot clear and straight forward to most.

And if you have to ask for their first name and last name individually, you'd be better off providing some hints. For instance:

- **First Name** is also referred to as the **Given Name** or **Christian Name**.
- **Last Name** is also often called the **Family Name** or **Surname**.
- Alternatively, you can provide a hint like this:

  **Example:** *Will* (first name), *Smith* (last name) as in *Will Smith*

Not that this is the best way to do it, but it helps. :) Depends on your target audience as well.

Comment: 1. who said non-english speaking countries dosent know the diff b/w first name and surname? Do you have evidence? Rabindranath tagore - Rabindranath first name, tagore - surname  - reference of Indian name with first name and surname! 2. how to identify target audiance before they register?

Comment: @sree **(1)** *may not* and *do not* have very different meanings. **(2)** You don't need evidence to say that. It's commonsense. If everyone knew the meaning of first name and last name, there wouldn't be [so many questions about them](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=first+name+and+last+name+means) on the web.

Comment: @sree `2. how to identify target audience before they register?` Simple answer is, `you should know your target audience`. You do not start a project without knowing your target audience (or put it this way, the country, or region of population you would like to target). And still don't understand how my question offended you. :)

Comment: my friend nothing offended me... i was thinking the other way, means, does all english speaking country know their surname last name etc... (2) targeting audience like that would be difficult for a general app isnt it? unless its geo based sites ? :)

Comment: @sree `(2) targeting audience like that would be difficult for a general app isnt it? unless its geo based sites ?` When we do not have a specific target audience, we should prepare for the worst -- i.e., try to make the registration form more understandable , as best as you can.

Comment: @Sree I will agree with geekpanth3r, It doesn't matter whether they have firstname and lastname or not, what matters is that how many of them understand it well and what is they are comfortable with. I decide to just say, fullname or say 'Your name' so that everyone can just write their fullname or what ever part they want to use.

Comment: @Hafiz that should be fine for me too :)

Comment: @geekpanth3r lol :)

Comment: If your site is targeting non english speaking countries, you should have a language file in your app that is written in their language. Like I know what to do when I land on a Japanese site? Your best bet is, keep it simple and stick to what people already know and can identify with without having to think about it which can be counted as a distraction.

Comment: In the portuguese-speaking world, it is common to have e.g. 2 "given names" and 2 or 3 (sometimes 4!) "family names". So, it might be better to say "Name(s)". Another thing that often confuses me are sites asking for my "middle name". That's something purely anglo-saxon, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

[image: FB]

I'd use the above, 800 million people used it fine ;)

Comment: Just include "name" after First, Middle, and Last :D

Answer (score 1):

Well, most of the government driven sites/apps need your fullname along with your last name initial etc because they rely on high accuracy of data. For example passport registration needs your fullname , surname etc because they want to clearly distinguish each person based on name. Here, fullname is useful since it has to be printed on a authenticated passport.

On the other hand , you can simply use name or nick name only in cases where your registration does not connect to high data accuracy or authenticity , for example social networks, gaming sites etc need not have  fullname, surname since, these are less worried when they want to display your name.

Answer (score 1):

I agreed with these both answered, it's advisable to keep sign up form as simple as possible, fields are depend on your business or site requirements, firstly we should analyze our users and business requirement.. create a list of all fields which usually used in signup form, then think on them one by one, are they really needed for your website or business even for future, if yes then keep them in your form but at same time think from user side, can user give you that info without any hesitation and your form is still simple to fill in.

Answer (score 0):

In some countries or communities, people provide their Surname as First name. If you have a box called "Full name:", then you'll have to assume the name before the "space" as First name. While Providing "First name" and "Last name" as clear boxes, people would know where to fill each.