# Intuitive cross-cultural terms for full name and name-to-be-addressed-as

Tags: internationalisation, names

If a user interface only deals with English or European languages, it's usually quite straightforward to split a user's name into `given_name` and `surname`. This way, you can easily do things like:

- "Dear `given_name`"
- "`given_name`'s Account"
- "This item was created by `given_name` `surname`"

And so on, translated into various languages.

However, if you've got users from countries such as China, this approach isn't so good. In general, you don't want to address Chinese users using only their first name, but by their full name.

To me, the more global way to separate names seems to be a `full_name` field and a `name_to_be_addressed_as` field. So a European user could put 'Joe Bloggs' for the first one, and 'Joe' for the second, whilst a Chinese user could put '宋浩然' for both of them (or whatever they like, of course).

Note that in my situation I do need a full / formal name to refer to users at times.

**My question is, how can I name these fields so that e.g. European users get the idea without having to know why it's implemented that way?**

Currently, I'm asking for 'Full name:' and 'Address me as: ', but that seems quite cumbersome and unintuitive. I'm also considering 'Formal name:' and 'Friendly name:', but that also seems quite weird.

What would be a better approach?

(I'm in not asking for translated terms in different languages - what I'm looking for are two general concepts that I can then translate.)

Comment: Why not simply using "Full name" and "Nickname" ?

Comment: Most sites I know use "Full name" and "Display name".

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise: Because my display name may not be my nickname. "Nickname" has extra connotations and also may be private or affectionate and not something you want to share with the world. I know it has come to be understood as an alias for "display name" but I would advice against perpetuating that notion. "Display name" conveys exactly what it does and does not suffer from extra baggage.

Comment: A widely accepted answer to another question was to phrase the preferred name as a question, "What should I call you?":  http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/15770/merging-firstname-last-name-into-one-field/15778#15778.  I did this on my own site's contact form before eventually dropping that field to simplify the form.

Answer (score 2):

The following is an idea that may be simpler to the users but which involves more effort programmatically:

Internationalized Data Model

- have `given_name`, `family_name` and `full_name` as separate fields in your database
- in your database, make `given_name` and `family_name` optional, `full_name` required

When users are in the American/European context of your website

- in your signup form, show `given_name` and `family_name` in countries where it makes sense; when they are completed, merge the two fields (and anything else that you capture like `title` or `middle_name` into `full_name`) when you save your record to the database
- when you display the name, if `given_name` is available, show that; otherwise show `full_name`

When users are in the Chinese context of your website

- In your signup form, show `full_name` field only
- When you display the name, always show `full_name`

Conceivably you would want to either elaborate this for other contexts, and probably set up the `full_name` Chinese scenario as the default handling.

I specify "in ... context", because you must anticipate that a user might want to alternate; e.g. if a bilingual English/Chinese person in Hong Kong can't find what they're looking for in the Chinese version, that they might switch to English. So they may have created their account in one language and begin using the site in another. Therefore you want to

Answer (score 0):

Indeed a very good question I also deal with at work. We set is as: name(s),; last name,; preferred addressing. Then you can have some options that the users will chose from (radio buttons yeyy!)